# Can we prove the greedy algorithm archives 1.5-approximation for the Minimal Dominating Set Problem?

Tags: graphs, approximation, greedy-algorithms

The following approximation algorithm for the *Minimal Dominating Set Problem* is said by a fellow student to be a 1.5-approximation:

1. Start with empty set $S$
2. As long as not all vertices are covered:

   - Add a vertex that is not in $S$
     with the most uncovered neighbors including itself.
   - Mark it and all its neighbors as covered
3. return $S$

I can't find a proof for the approximation ratio however and my own attempts to prove it have failed so far since I lack the right approach to proof something like this.

Comment: Can you provide the source of this claim (link/book/..)

Comment: Yes, it would be interesting to know where you got that information. Not only is the claim incorrect, but Dominating Set is APX-hard, which means it's likely that *no* polynomial-time algorithm is able to approximate this problem to a constant ratio.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/158968/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4656428/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: @NarekBojikian it's nothing official, just a fellow students claim, I don't know if he relied on any supposedly reliable source.

Comment: @D.W. got, it - I will delete the other question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This claim is incorrect. The diagram below shows a small counterexample:

[image: A small counterexample]

Consider two different runs of the greedy algorithm that break ties in different ways:

1. Run 1 chooses the 6 red vertices in order from darkest to lightest, then chooses the yellow vertex.
2. Run 2 chooses the 3 green vertices in order from darkest to lightest, then chooses the yellow vertex.

(Check for yourself that each run is a valid possible execution of the algorithm.) The first run chooses a solution of size 7; the second, an (optimal) solution of size 4. $7/4 = 1.75 > 1.5$, meaning the greedy algorithm is capable of producing a solution that violates the claimed bound.

Comment: Thank you very much. That seems to indicate that the algorithm could be a 2-approximation since your example could be expanded to something similar but with the optimal solution being n and the worst case being $(2n-1)/(n)$, however Highheath states under my question, that a constant ratio approximation is unlikely to exist . I'm afraid, I am still missing an approach to determine and proof the actual approximation ratio.

Comment: You're welcome. The Wikipedia page on Dominating Set is helpful.